# Evaluating a path integral without being given a parametrization

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Find the mass of the wire formed by the intersection of the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ and the plane $x + z = 0$ if the density of the wire is $6y^2$ grams per unit length.

I am completely stuck on this problem. I found out that the plane and sphere intersect when $2x^2 + y^2 = 1$, which can be parametrized as $c(t) = $. Evaluating $f(c(t))$, I got $6(\sin(t))^2$. From here, the process went downhill. When attempting to evaluate the norm of $c'(t)$, I got a complex expression that, when multiplied by $f(c(t))$, becomes seemingly un-integrable. Where did I go wrong and how is this problem solved?

Comment: Hint: use delta functions.